If every congruent class contains only one element, then the set is finite.
I would like to ask a question to clarify a query I posted yesterday on every numerical Semigroup is finitely generated. Let's start with the following:
Suppose we have a set $ A \subseteq \mathbb{N} $ and let $ m$ be the smallest element of $ A $.
Now, if we assume that for any two elements $ n, n' \in A $ we have $ n \not\equiv n' \pmod{m} $, then we conclude that $ A $ is a finite set. But how does it become finite? It may seem simple, or maybe not, but it is not clear to me. Please help me understand this.
Expanding the question using another approach:
To grasp the above concept, it's crucial to understand the following:
If we have $A\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ and $m$ as the smallest element of $A$, and if for all $n, n' \in A$ it holds that $n \not\equiv n' \pmod{m}$, we can define the equivalence relation as follows: $n\sim n'$ if and only if $n\equiv n' \pmod{m}$. Now, the objective is to demonstrate that the cardinality of the quotient space $A/\sim$ is $m$.

There are only $m$ congruence classes, and there is at most one element of $A$ in each congruence class, so $A$ can have at most $m$ elements.

Please can you explain this to me, you say that there is only $m$ congruence classes, and that's mean the cardinal of the quotient space $A/\sim$ is $m$ where $n\sim n'$ iff $n\equiv n'$ mod $m$. But why this cardinal is $m$?

This is an application of the pigeonhole principle.  There are only $m$ different congruence classes $\bmod m$.  We are told that each of these congruence classes has at most $1$ element of $A$, because if any congruence class had two elements of $A$, say $n$ and $n'$, then we would have $n \equiv n' \pmod m$, contrary to our assumption.
But now we have finitely many (in fact, $m$ many) congruence classes that partition all of $\Bbb N$, and each class can have at most $1$ element of $A$.  That means $A$ can have at most $m$ different elements.  Put another way, if $A$ has more than $m$ elements, then at least two of those elements must be in the same congruence class $\bmod m$, and (contrary to our assumption), those two different elements of $A$ are congruent $\bmod m$.

Here is my question, you say '' if $A$ has more than $m$ elements, then at least two of those elements must be in the same congruence class $\bmod m$'', why this happen I need a clear answer please.
